# Where can I view advanced wireless properties to find out channel no, SNR, etc in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

In Linux there's iwconfig, iwlist, etc.

In Windows, is there anyway to get more advanced view of the properties/statistics of the wifi signals I see? Something other than the couple of bars and the standard IP settings? Ideally I'd like some information to help troubleshoot connectivity problems-- IE what channel my neighbor's wifi is on, what the SNR of my wifi is, etc.

If no such thing exists is there software available that would give me that information?

Comment: Necro, but might b stumbled on in a search, so...This can be done from CMD window with: netsh wlam show all (and scroll to the bottom to see SSID info including channel numbers, auth type, signal rate, radioo type, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer that seems to do the trick. There's a couple Windows tools to download that give you advanced Wireless information:

1. Netstumbler: http://www.netstumbler.com
2. Inssider: http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider

I ended up going with Inssider becaues it worked with my usb adapter while NetStumbler did not. Also as @jason404 says, netstumbler won't work for Windows for Vista or Win7.

Comment: Just a note to mention that NetStumbler does not work with Vista or Win7 onwards.